# Ubuntu won't boot after install. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: boot, grub2

I installed a light (mini) Version of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a secondary machine. After I got over 7,000 package-dependency errors, I continued the installation and proceeded to install grub on `sda1` (however there is only one hard drive).

Is there a problem, because I installed just a few packages? I didn't know which ones to take.

Comment: What "light" version of Ubuntu are you talking about? If you need something lightweight, there's Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Comment: You do not install grub to a partition like sda1, just to the MBR or first sector of hard drive like sda, not sda1. If sda1 was NTFS it will need repair with testdisk.

Answer (score 0):

If by "mini" version, you mean the image found [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso), then my guess is that your machine didn't connect to the internet, and didn't pull down the required packages to do an install.

The mini.iso and netinstall images **require** an active internet connection at install time. They contain minimal packages required *only to boot*, which is why the images are so small.

You could re-run the installer and pay close attention to the networking portion to ensure that it's properly connected.

If the mini.iso installer doesn't detect your networking devices, you'll have to use one of the larger images to successfully install, since they contain the required packages on disk.